# How to fix the error of bottle route keep loading when reading file from url?

Tags: python-3.x, bottle

I need to save the file sent by the url 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/getjourney'.
When I run the program by a python file code works. But while routing the function with same code through a function browser stuck in loading and server crashes. Can you please help me solving this problem?

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bottle import run, route, template, request, get, post
from urllib.parse import urlparse


@get("/getjourney")
def getjourney():
    response = "Journey1"
    f = open('XML files/' + response + '.xml').read()
    return "f"


@route('/savejourney')
def savejourney():
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/getjourney'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    xml1 = response.read()
    print(xml1)
    xml = open('../XML files/new.xml', "w")
    xml.write(str(xml1))
```

I expect to save the file returned by url 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/getjourney' in a folder.

Comment: Welcome! You'll need to elaborate on "server crashes" so we can help you. How does it crash? Include the important parts of the crash dump (e.g. the exception and stack trace).

Answer (score 0):

your browsers tries to display/render this xml content. it might cause some bug in doing so. try this and see if it works for you:

```
import html
@get("/getjourney")
def getjourney():
    response = "Journey1"
    f = open('XML files/' + response + '.xml').read()
    return html.escape(f)
```